# Python pandas: add index column based on existing columns, with duplicates sharing the same index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I would like to add an index column based on existing columns. Duplicates would share the same index. For example,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdOH5.png)

If the values for the two columns ['old_index','year'] are the same, then the new index would be same. The value in the column 'num' does not matter.

I'm wondering if anyone can help. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Consider making a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the section [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking another question.

Comment: Thanks! I'd be sure to follow this next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['new_id'] = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist(), sort=False).ngroup() + 1
df


index   year    id  new_id
0   1   2000    5   1
1   2   1996    3   2
2   2   1996    3   2
3   4   1994    2   3
4   4   1999    4   4
5   4   1999    4   4
6   12  1989    1   5
7   12  1989    1   5
8   12  1985    0   6
9   12  2011    6   7
```

Give this a try, but let me know if it isn't fully what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It did work. I just edited the question, could you please check it? I'm looking for a way that works on selected columns.

Comment: @Arist. I just edited my answer. Try that new line of code

Comment: yes it works. I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Be sure to click the check arrow to indicate your question has been answered next to my submission. @Arist

Comment: Just did. I'm new to Stackoverflow. Thanks for reminding me.